# Find all emails in files and replace with specific email

Tags: find

How can I find all emails in php files and replace with an email?

```
find . -iname '*.php' -exec grep -E -o "\b[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+\b" -exec sed -i 's//email@domain.com/g' {} \;
```

Comment: Is there no way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find emails in php files command is:

```
find . -iname '*.php' -exec grep -E -o "\b[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+\b" {} \;
```

and replace command is:

```
find . -iname '*.php' -type f -exec sed -i 's/old-email@domain.com/new-email@domain.com/g' {} \;
```

But I don't know exactly how to join them in one command.
Any ideas?